# How to use logic if else in json schema to validate array item?

Tags: json, jsonschema

i have json like this

> {   "user" : ["foo", "bar"] }

i want use if else here

if there "foo" in array user then field admin is required

I've tried it like this

```
 {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "title": "JSON Schema for role",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "user": {
            "type": ["array"],
          "items" : {
          "type" : "string",
            "enum" : [
            "foo",
              "bar"
            ]
          }
        },
      "admin" : {"type" : "string"},
     "if": {
    "properties": {
      "user": { "const": "foo" }
    },
    "required": ["user"]
  },
  "then": { "required": ["admin"] }
    },"additionalProperties": false}
```

but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` is applicable to single values, but you want to check the contense of an array.

You want `contains`. `contains` applies it's value (which is a subschema) to each item in the array, to check at least one of the items is what is expected.

You also needed to have your `if` and `then` keywords be part of a schema object. You had them as part of the `properties` object.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "title": "JSON Schema for role",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "user": {
      "type": [
        "array"
      ],
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "foo",
          "bar"
        ]
      }
    },
    "admin": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "user"
  ],
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "user": {
        "contains": {
          "type": "string",
          "const": "foo"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "required": [
      "admin"
    ]
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

See it working: https://jsonschema.dev/s/RaxvK

Comment: Welcome! If you consider the linked service helpful, please consider supporting its further development =]